# Clarification about daily cap and accepted answers

Tags: support, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I read in [FAQ about daily cap limit](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) and that it does not include accepted answers. However it can be read in 2 ways:

- The 15 points for accepted answer is not included
- The upvotes on accepted answer are not included

Which way of reading is correct? Could the FAQ be clarified?

Comment: I was about to make a new question requesting this clarification when I saw this question.  It really is confusing/misleading and I think the FAQ should clarify it.  Indeed I interpreted it as though one could earn say 515 points in a day with a single answer that got accepted along with 50 upvotes.

Comment: I agree.  I was also completely confused by this until just now!

Comment: Actually, what am I talking about: Should be dupe of [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/230261) (already [tag:faq]), not the one I flagged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just the 15 points for having the accepted answer that's immune, but I suppose the FAQ does seem to imply it's all points from an accepted answer. Should it say "accepted answer bonuses"?

Comment: How about "the answer acceptance bonus," or even "the +15 answer acceptance bonus"?

Comment: @Pop I'm ok with either, but I was trying to avoid duplicating the "+15" that's mentioned two lines above that one

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to be painfully clear.  I'm not in love with it.

Comment: I think perhaps they could change it to "...while answers accepted after reaching the limit are not subject, and still reward reputation." or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

The following sentence is the referring to both the reputation you gain when one of your answers is accepted, and the reputation you gain when you accept an answer.
I verified that personally, as when I accepted answers, the gained reputation was not counted for reaching the reputation cap.

> Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

As both the reputations are listed under *answer is accepted*, they don't count for reaching the reputation cap.

> answer is accepted       +15        (+2 to acceptor)

Comment: I don't think he's referring to the `+2`.  I think by `The upvotes on accepted answer are not included` he means that `if you had 40 upvotes on this answer (in 1 day) and he *accepts* it, then you get 400 points in one day.`  I believe it's a minor point of confusion which could be sorted out with a simple rewording.

Comment: Well, that is what I have experienced. When I had more than 200 points in a day, the reputation I got from answers I accepted was not counted.

Comment: Yep.  You are absolutely correct.  I was just trying to clarify that I don't think Maciej was focusing on the +2.  I think he was curious about the upvotes.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: @M. Tibbits I'm pretty sure that's what OP was referring to, and I *know* that's what I'm referring to (I am the one that set the bounty).  I would like to see some sort of clarification in the FAQ.

Comment: Maciej is asking if up-votes on accepted answers are excluded from the reputation cap; to which I have answered that "reputation on accepted answers" is referring only to the +15, and +2.

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ is terribly unclear and in my opinion it needs to be clarified.  It is apparently only the 15 points for acceptance that are immune, but one wouldn't know that strictly from reading the FAQ.

I attempted to revive this question by offering the bounty so that it could get attention by some mods that have the power to clarify the FAQ, but apparently that did not work.  Mods, I kindly request you to please consider clarifying the language in the FAQ to unambiguously explain this facet of how the reputation cap works.