# How does starting a bounty interact with exceeding the reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, bounties, daily-reputation-badges

If I hit/exceed the daily reputation cap on a day, then start a bounty so that my net reputation gain is less than 200, does it still count as hitting/exceeding the reputation cap for the purposes of the Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges?

E.g., if I received 25 answer upvotes and 4 acceptances (totaling 260 *received* reputation) and started a bounty of 200, would that day count toward those badges even though the net reputation for the day was only 60 and not 200?

I apologize if this is a trivial question, but I'm curious since if it counts against these badges then I think we're motivating the wrong behavior — you're better off not starting bounties on days when you're earning a lot of reputation.

Comment: Most of us don't have that problem. :-)

Comment: Epic/Legendary is not CONSECUTIVE days, unlike Enthusiast/Fanatic, so it is hardly a problem at all. People who would care would at most wait another day or two.

Comment: That's true, but it still seems odd to force people to exceed the reputation cap a few more times just because they were investing the points they'd earned trying to get an answer to a question.

Comment: Point 2 of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121553/226495) to ["200 point maximum, bounties and badges"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121531/226495) indicates that such a day does **not** count toward badges.

Answer (score 1):

Bounty is excluded from rep cap. If your bounty is 200, you cannot recover it from questions - sorry.

The 200/day rep cap applies (only) to

```
+10 Your Answer was upvoted
+ 5 Your Question was upvoted
+ 2 Accept answer to a question
+ 2 Your Suggested Edit was accepted
- 2 Your Question/Answer was downvoted
- 1 You Downvoted an Question/Answer
```

Comment: It could be made clearer that *starting* a bounty does not count against earning a Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badge. Also, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103577/226495) implies *accepting* an answer does not count toward the rep cap. I *think* received bounties (and acceptances) count toward the badges even though they do not count toward the rep cap.