# If I start a bounty, do I need to earn more points to make progress toward Epic?

Tags: support, bounties, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounties and Epic/legendary progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163271/bounties-and-epic-legendary-progress)

If I start a bounty of 500 points on a question, that amount is immediately subtracted from my reputation.  I'm aware that the bounty points *awarded* to a user are immune from the daily rep-cap, but I haven't seen it spelled out anywhere how that influences the *awarder*.  e.g.,

- Do I now need to earn 700 points today in order make progress toward an Epic/Legendary badge?
- Do I still have the ability to earn only 200 points before I hit the reputation cap for the day, or is it possible for me to earn 700 points before hitting the cap the day?
- Does it negatively influence my position in the reputation leagues?

None of this stuff really matters either way -- I suppose I'm just curious how it works.

As a side note, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83337/how-does-starting-a-bounty-interact-with-exceeding-the-reputation-cap) is a duplicate of a portion of my question, but it is almost 2 years old now, and the only answer provided doesn't give any references in support -- In short, I'm not sure if I believe it :-).  Additionally, that answer is pretty-unclear.  First it states that bounty is excluded from rep-cap, then it says you can't recover -- I'm not exactly sure what it means.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yes, I suppose so.  That doesn't address how the bounty plays with the rep-cap though.

Comment: The rep-cap would still apply; 200 points from upvotes on questions and answers only. You don't get to extend that by loosing points to a bonus payment. :-)

Comment: And yes, it influences the leagues, I'm 99% certain of that.

Comment: I suppose I need to improve my meta - googling skills :)