# Daily reputation limit and accepted answers

Tags: bug, reputation, accepted-answer, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarification about daily cap and accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62973/clarification-about-daily-cap-and-accepted-answers)

The FAQ for reputation daily limit says:

> accepted answers ... are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

but the lifting of the limit seems to apply only to the actual accept event, not for upvotes of accepted answers. The wording doesn't make the distinction between event types, thus suggesting that reputation limits are waived for accepted answers, but this isn't the case.

Is this the intention? If not, it's a bug. If so, the wording in the FAQ should be more precise.

Comment: Playing the word game, are we? I guess if you take it *that literally*. I personally think it's a bit absurd to expect that just because an answer is now accepted it's now magically immune to the limit.

Comment: @animuson Absurd? Well, that's what I expected it to mean, because that's what it says! It doesn't say "the reputation gained by the acceptance of your answer..."

Comment: @animuson It's not absurd at all...that's how it reads right now.  There's also the fact that it's widely known that several members regularly exceed the rep cap, so it's very reasonable to assume that that is how they accomplish this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, I suppose it could be clearer. Perhaps even mentioning the amount of rep that is applicable:

> The reputation earned from the acceptance of an answer (+15) does not count toward the daily reputation limit.

Comment: I think the +2 from accepting an answer is also immune.

Comment: Ah I see, so maybe that should read `(+2 or +15)`...

Comment: Though, I'd suspect, the majority of people who hit their rap caps on a regular basis aren't asking a lot of questions. :-)

Comment: People who hit the rep cap on a regular basis generally don't need to go to the FAQ to know the rep cap rules.  It's the newer people who rarely hit the rep cap but ask/answer one good question to hit it on rare occasions that go to the FAQ looking to understand the rep cap.

Comment: @Servy I understand. I was making a joke.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be clearer if it said:

> while reputation gained from accepting an answer, having an answer accepted, and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

I can imagine somebody could understand the current phrase as saying the reputation (up-votes, down-votes, and the final +15) gained from an answer that is then accepted doesn't count toward the daily limit, while the phrase is referring to the reputation you gain when you accept an answer (+2), and the reputation you gain when an answer of yours is accepted (+15).