# Daily reputation limit and high reputations values

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Since there is a daily rep limit of 200, how can users with who have been members for less than 5 years have 400k reputation?

```
400k/200/365=5.47
```

Comment: You can still get rep by other methods regardless of the cap. I think having your answers accepted can put you over the rep cap.

Comment: It's Jon Skeet. He was answering SO questions before SO was created. On a serious note, you can get points above and beyond the daily rep limit from having answers accepted and accepting answers on your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there are other things that don't count toward the daily limit, e.g. +15 for an accept of your answer, +2 for accepting someone's answer, bounties, etc. I've received over 300 on many days mostly because of accepts.

[From the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

However note that it was [recently suggested the wording be made more clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139962/daily-reputation-limit-and-accepted-answers/).