# Extra Rep Cap Buffer from Answer Accepts?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, daily-reputation-limit

I capped on Code Review today, but I had a curious revelation in doing so.  I accepted one of my ancient answers on a question of mine that never got any others, and had another answer be accepted.  I thought that accepting my own answer would not add to the rep cap buffer, but I earned 219 rep, 4 above the 15 point buffer created by the other accept.  Is this a bug, or is it planned to do this?

Comment: you do know that all UVs on answers after they that have been accepted do not count towards the limit.

Comment: No, I did not know that.  I've only had the 15 points from the accept count before, unless I didn't get any upvotes on that day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rep *you* gain from accepting *others'* answers is evidently *also* not subject to the cap. You accepted [two](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103965/remove-empty-argument-lists-from-attributes/106643#106643) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114050/you-are-promoted-you-are-promoted-we-all-are-promoted/114154#114154) that day, for +4 total, which perfectly explains the discrepancy.

This has [previously been documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103577/274165).

Answer (score 0):

The rep limit only limits rep gained from up votes on question and unaccepted answers.

Bounties and accepted answers are exempt from the limit; not just the 15 from the accept, but all the UVs after it is accepted too. (Hence how folks like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=graph) always get more then 200)

However all up votes "lost" to the rep cap on unaccepted answers will not be given out once the answer is accepted.

Comment: This [just isn't so at all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk8JU.png).